# MSVC linker Export of characters from an executable file without a .exp file

Tags: windows, visual-c++, linker, linker-flags

I want to export characters from an executable file without its .exp file using /FORCE:UNRESOLVED

I tried to use even [delayed loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=msvc-170) together with [/FORCE:UNRESOLVED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/force-force-file-output?view=msvc-170), but it doesn't help, I probably need to use some analogue of the ld64 [-undefined dynamic_lookup](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ld64/)command here, but I don't know its name for the MSVC linker

> Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options
> are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup.  The
> default is error.

I also used /EXPORT for symbol from executable and /INCLUDE flags for dll